# C# - Property return a lenght array

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, get, set

I have three class :

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
};

public class count
{
    public int number
    {
        get
        {
            return 1;
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
}

public class myclass
{
    public Customer[] Customer { get; set; }

    public count number { get; set; }
}
```

And one instance :

```
myclass myclass = new myclass()
{
    Customer = new Customer[]
    {
        new Customer()
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName1",
            LastName = "LastName1"
        },
        new Customer()
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName2",
            LastName = "LastName2"
        }
    },
    number = new count()
};
```

I want the property count.number returns the number of customer in my array Customer[].

I must have a different class to get the number of elements of my array Customer[]

How to do ?

Th

Comment: How about `Customer.Lenght`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property shouldn't have a setter, it should just return the length of the array dynamically.  Something like this:

```
public class myclass
{
    public Customer[] Customer { get; set; }

    public int number
    {
        get { return Customer.Length; }
    }
}
```

Then you don't have to manually set it (or, more importantly, *manually* keep it synchronized as the array changes).

If you *must* wrap that integer in a class (which you really *shouldn't* need to, but whatever), then just return an instance of that class:

```
public class myclass
{
    public Customer[] Customer { get; set; }

    public count number
    {
        get { return new count { number = Customer.Length; } }
    }
}
```

However you structure it (that is, whatever reason you have for wrapping primitive values in classes), the point is that you can get the `.Length` of an array on the fly without having to manually keep track of it yourself.  The array knows how long it is.